# Java - How to get new command line arguments

Tags: java, eclipse, arguments

I have a Java program with takes a string argument as such:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         // Something happens here // 
    }
```

My question is, how do i, in case they exist, get any NEW command line arguments that might have been passed ?

To explain myself: i know how to access the args array. What i don't know is how do i update it with NEW arguments (that are NOT typed in, but automatic command line arguments).

Comment: It is a String array. The array will have all the command line arguments passed.

Comment: @R.J, why not to post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @AlexR - Would have done that but I was kind of busy with something else. Nevertheless, an answer is now available, so no issues :)

Answer (score 1):

As I conclude from your question, you want to get/use command-line-arguments in your code, So this can be achieved by :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++){   // since args is an array of String
          System.out.println(args[i]);
     }
}
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer. However this is not what i am trying to do. i already have the arguments, however the program i am using is sending me NEW arguments every time i system.out.println() to it. How to i get those NEW arguments ?

Comment: For example i tried getting it using a String test = System.console().readLine(); however i get null pointer exception

Comment: `System.console().readLine();` reads a single line of text from the console and not the command-line-arguments, however, from where and how you will get **NEW** and **Automatic** cmd-line-args???

Comment: The new arguments are sent by a server. HOW do i get the new args, is exactly what i am asking.

Answer (score 0):

main method takes an array of string, which means that when you run your code with multiple parametres, e.g.

```
java MainClass param1 param2 param3
```

You can just access them from String[] table like this:

```
args[0]  // param1
args[1]  // param2
args[2]  // param3
```

And so on. See official [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

All command line arguments are passed to the paramater of the main methode which is of type string array.

To loop through them use:

```
for(String arg : args)
{
   System.out.println(arg);
}
```

To get a single one use:

```
System.out.println(args[0]);
```

or

```
System.out.println(args[1]);
```